# ggplot2 claims that `inherit` must be a R6ClassGenerator

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-package, cran

I'm trying to build an R package vignette with a very simple call to `ggplot2` (plotting an ROC curve):

`ggplot(ValidationRocPoints, aes(x = falsePositiveRate, y = truePositiveRate)) + geom_line()`

(`ValidationRocPoints` is a list containing ROC curve data.)

I can run this fine from my Mac, but when I use the [CRAN Win-Builder](https://win-builder.r-project.org), I get the following error:

> - checking re-building of vignette outputs ... [32s] WARNING
>     Error(s) in re-building vignettes:
>     --- re-building 'AdvancedVignette.Rmd' using rmarkdown
>     Quitting from lines 173-184 (AdvancedVignette.Rmd) 
>     Error: processing vignette 'AdvancedVignette.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
>     `inherit` must be a R6ClassGenerator.
>     --- failed re-building 'AdvancedVignette.Rmd'

I'm unsure what is going on.

Comment: can you post your data (using `dput(head(data))` so we can help reproduce this?

Comment: I'm getting a similar error when trying to check a package on Windows R devel, see this gist for replication https://gist.github.com/andybega/abed6a8dc097f86d936f61b377480e63

Comment: FYI, when I re-run the checks on R-devel win-builder now, the issue is resolved. I don't think I made any code changes that would have fixed this, so no idea what happened to resolve it.

Comment: @andybega My issue also spontaneously got resolved. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @peterhurford thanks, and thanks for asking the question on SO. It was the only lead on this issue that I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming across this in the future, it appears that the problem was a temporary issue on CRAN win-builder that was resolved. Here's the [related ggplot2 issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3063) to that effect.